# Win32_Process running slow since Windows 7 (2017) update

Tags: vbscript, windows-7, win32-process

I have a small VBScript, which looks for specific applications via the Win32_Process. This was working witout any lag but since the recent 2017 1GB+ Windows 7 update, this process is now taking several seconds to return a couple of lines.

I have isolated the code down to a script, which runs the query and I've included a MsgBox either side of the call to Win32_Process and this is definitely the issue.

The test script is in a shared location and I've run it from a Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 environment and both return immediately without any lag as soon as I confirm the first MsgBox.

Here's the code I'me running:

```
strProcessSQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE " & _
    "Name = 'WScript.exe' OR Name = 'CScript.exe'" & _
    " OR " & _
    "Name = 'mshta.exe'" & _
    " OR " & _
    "Name = 'mstsc.exe'" & _
    " OR " & _
    "Name = 'prowin32.exe' OR Name = 'prowc.exe'"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Msgbox "Query Starting"

Set objProcessElements = objWMIService.ExecQuery (strProcessSQLQuery)

Msgbox "Query Completed: " & objProcessElements.Count
```

Comment: Is this only on one specific system, or is this occurring across multiple systems clearly coinciding with when that system gets updated?

Comment: I have tested this on another PC, which also is running Windows 7 and again since the update has also started to encounter this lag. Originally I thought it may have been a security issue with my AD login but I've logged in as myself and other users on the Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 PC and both work as expected with no lag. This process is also running on a Server 2012 environment and using the above script is not experiencing any lag.

Comment: I have located a Windows 7 PC which still has not been updated with the latest patch and run the same script. The response is instantaneous with zero lag. I'm pretty much convinced that something has changed since this latest update, which is impacting how the Win32_Process is handling queries but have come to a stop as I do not how to either code around it or find an alternative.

Comment: I started the Windows 7 PC up in safe mode and executed the script, which immediately returned the query, with 0 lag. I'm trying ti ascertain which windows service would impact the win32_process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the recent Windows 7 updates, post my question have resolved the issue. Whatever the patches have addressed has fixed the Win32_process response times.